# Angular js page and twitter share

Tags: angularjs, url, twitter, hashtag

I am trying to share a page on twitter using twitter Java Script API.

The issue is that the url contains an hash tag # since it is a page built with Angular JS and twitter cuts off the piece of URL that follows the hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out that the hash sign `#` can be substituted with `%23`. So the link in the template became

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url={{twitterfullurl}}" ...
```

And in the controller I've changed the url in this way:

```
$scope.twitterfullurl = $scope.fullurl.replace('#', '%23');
```